# Magento 1.9 error 500 on specific store view

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, http-error-500

I'm having issues with change to store view,

I have this site: https://example.com/ working OK

but when i try to change the language (so, the store view),

> http://example.com/?___store=english&___from_store=spanish

I just see the Error 500, and the site stop working until clear the cookies of the browser.

I don't know, because i have the same code in another server, and the code works fine.

This error happens only in the page with some products data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check logs in server and post their content with question.

Comment: Apache logs says: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 512 bytes) in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291\n'

Comment: It's weird, because I have 8GB as memory_limit, but the error comes with just 1GB

Answer (score 2):

This is a server error. 
if you have a developer store, please go to index.php under your root magento store and enable developer mode. 
Just paste this code after line 72 
`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`
and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  if it is commented.
Then you are able to view the error and can research for it on google or can comment here.

Comment: Apache logs says: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 512 bytes) in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291\n'

Comment: But in my php info, i have 6000M of memory_limit, but still going down on 1073741824 bytes (1GB), so i don't understand, this happens only on 1 storeview

Comment: And the server have 15GB of memory

Comment: Can you send what magento shows after enablung deceloper mode in the way I told you please?

Comment: Sure: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 87 bytes) in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291

Comment: Is the same error